# Why does my sink faucet send water to the bathtub?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

When I turn on the water to the sink, it sends water to the tub & shower. Why would this happen?

Comment: Can you provide more information: type of residence (house or apartment), your location, are both hot and cold water involved?, how long has this been going on?, etc.

Comment: Also, does it happen the other way around at all? If you're running the shower, does anything come out of the sink?

Comment: Has anyone done any plumbing work lately?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about water backing up in the drains there is a down line obstruction and a snake or jetting may be required as the problem normally continues to get worse until totally plugged.